# Криво устанавливается OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv, cv2

OpenCv правильно импортируется и никаких ошибок нету, но при работе имеется только 3 функции:

1. `cv2.bootstrap()`
2. `cv2.__load_extra_py_code_for_module(base, name, enable_debug_print=False)`
3. `cv2.__collect_extra_submodules(enable_debug_print=False)`

пример установки:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

код куда обращается cv2 при импорте:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rMedGX26dCeIIQajiH_AhfZJGCkrvauM/view?usp=share_link

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вы поняли, что там есть только эти три функции?

Comment: Залез в сам файл init и сам PyCharm подсказывает только 3 функции

Comment: А при импорте других функций, кроме этих трёх, выдает ошибку?

Comment: конечно же, иначе бы не писал сюда)

Comment: Как устанавливали? (Приведите ваши действия для установки OpenCV **прямо в вопросе** (вопрос можно править, нажав кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1500083/edit))).

Comment: Переустановил и оказывается что функции заработали, только в подсказках их всё так же нету

Answer (score 0):

На маке были точно также. Я перешел на Anaconda интерпретатор и использовал команду:

> pip3 install -U numpy==1.23.5 opencv-python==4.5.5.64